# Longtable: Illegal pream-token (\caption)

Tags: longtable

there is a table in my document that need to span over 2 pages. The compilation of the code gives me the following error message:

> Error message          ! Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token
>   (\caption): `c' used.
>
> See the array package documentation for explanation. Type  H  
>   for immediate help.  ...
>                                                      l.513                      \caption
>                       [Comparaison ...
>
> ?
>   This is my code:

Anyone could help me to fix it? Thanks.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{topcapt}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{rotfloat}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[square,sort,comma, authoryear]{natbib}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

    \setlength{\LTleft}{0pt}
    \begin{landscape}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{longtable}
                \caption[Comparaison]{Comparaison}
                \endfirsthead
                {{\tablename\ \thetable{} -- suite du tableau de la page précédente}} \\
                \endhead
                \hline
                \endlastfoot
                \noindent\makebox[\textwidth]
                {
                    \begin{tabular}{|p{0.13\textwidth}||p{0.40\textwidth}|p{0.40\textwidth}|p{0.08\textwidth}|p{0.08\textwidth}|p{0.07\textwidth}|p{0.08\textwidth}|p{0.08\textwidth}|p{0.08\textwidth}|p{0.08\textwidth}|}
                    \hline
                    \textbf{Attributs} & \thead{Caracté-\\ristiques}&\thead{Méthode}&\thead{Destina-\\taires}&\thead{Résulat}&\thead{}&\thead{Modu-\\larité}&\thead{Buts} & \thead{} & \thead{Docu-\\menta-\\tion}\\
                    \hline
                    \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{}\\
                    \hline
                    \textbf{Auteurs} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{}\\
                    \hline
                    \hline
                    \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{}\\
                    \hline
                    \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{}\\
                    \hline

                    \hline
                    \end{tabular}
                }
                \label{tab: comparaisonPatrons_1}
            \end{longtable}
        \end{center}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The longtable environment has a mandatory argument in which you specify the number of columns.  You need something like `\begin{longtable}{lll}` (or some `p`s or `r`s or whatever).  Since you have none, it thinks `\caption` is part of the mandatory argument for longtable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`longtable` takes the same column syntax as`tabular`, it should never be in `center` (the environment has no effect on it as it is full with) The horizontal with in`landscape` is `linewidth` not `\textwidth`

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{topcapt}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{rotfloat}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[square,sort,comma, authoryear]{natbib}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

    \begin{landscape}



            \begin{longtable}{|p{0.13\linewidth}||p{0.10\linewidth}|p{0.1\linewidth}|p{0.06\linewidth}|p{0.06\linewidth}|p{0.07\linewidth}|p{0.06\linewidth}|p{0.06\linewidth}|p{0.06\linewidth}|p{0.06\linewidth}|}
                \caption{Comparaison\label{tab: comparaisonPatrons_1}}
                \endfirsthead
                \caption[]{suite du tableau de la page précédente} \\
                \endhead
                \hline
                \endlastfoot
                    \hline
                    \textbf{Attributs} & \thead{Caracté-\\ristiques}&\thead{Méthode}&\thead{Destina-\\taires}&\thead{Résulat}&\thead{}&\thead{Modu-\\larité}&\thead{Buts} & \thead{} & \thead{Docu-\\menta-\\tion}\\
                    \hline
                    \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{}\\
                    \hline
                    \textbf{Auteurs} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{}\\
                    \hline
                    \hline
                    \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{}\\
                    \hline
                    \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{} & \footnotesize{}\\
                    \hline
            \end{longtable}

    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```